# if data empty, show error with knockout

Tags: javascript, model-view-controller, knockout.js

I'm pretty much new to knockout.js

I'm displaying some data from database in my mvc view. For now as data is always there it works fine. But i want to write a code which would say error/warning if data is empty (no purchased books for example) and i could offer a link to purchase new book with this error.

**This is how i display my data now**

```
var purchasedBooks = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model.Data));
            ko.applyBindings(new BookViewModel(purchasedBooks == null ? //doSomething : purchasedBooks));
```

Any help? I would like to display error inside div and also offer link to purchase new book. But would only like to show this div if there is no books.

```
<div class="book-p" data-bind="">
    <a href="#">Purchase new book!</a>
</div>
```

Comment: You can use the *if* binding: http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/if-binding.html

Comment: somehow doesnt work with the way i'm implementing things @Robert

Comment: Yeah, I suppose so... I think you should either go with Razor and do it the MVC way, *or* use AJAX and Knockout.js. Your current construction is a bit... ugly, to be honest.

Comment: Is purchasedBooks an array? Please update question with your ko model (BookViewModel) and what purchasedBooks looks like. This is simple to do with knockout, just need this info to help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's some simple knockout that maintains a count of items, and shows a different message depending of it the count is `0` or greater than `0`. Run the below snippet to test this solution.

```js
var viewModel = {  
  bookCount: ko.observable(0),
  addBook: function() {
    this.bookCount(this.bookCount() + 1)
  },
  removeBook: function() {
    if(this.bookCount() > 0)
      this.bookCount(this.bookCount() - 1)
  },
};

ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js">
</script>

<h2>Books:</h2>

<div data-bind="if: bookCount() > 0">
  <span data-bind="text: 'books in basket: ' + bookCount()"></span>
</div>

<div data-bind="if: bookCount() === 0">
  <span>no books in basket</span><br />
  <a href="#">Go here to buy some books</a>
</div>

<input type="button" value="add" 
       data-bind="click: addBook" />
<input type="button" value="remove" 
       data-bind="click: removeBook, visible: bookCount() > 0" />
```